# Bind JSON with list within records

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

When I have to consume a simple json I'm doing it this way

```
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", header);
            ResponseEntity<List<RelatorioResponse>> response = rt.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<RelatorioResponse>>() {
            });
            List<RelatorioResponse> responses = response.getBody();
```

My response Class

```
 @JsonProperty("relatorioID")
    private Integer relatorioID;

    @JsonProperty("professorID")
    private Integer professorID;

    @JsonProperty("alunoID")
    private Integer alunoID;

//getter setter
```

It's all coming out as expected, I can handle the data normally.

The problem is to receive data from a JSON with a list embedded in each record, 
like this:

```
[
  {
    "classID": 10,
    "id of students who missed class": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "classID": 20,
    "id of students who missed class": [
      3,
      4,
      8 
    ]
  }
]
```

complete json

```
 [{"classID":10,"id of students who missed class":[1,2]},{"classID":20,"id of students who missed class":[3,4]},
{"classID":50,"id of students who missed class":[2,33,9,45,35]},{"classID":56,"id of students who missed class":[1,6,7]},{"classID":20,"id of students who missed class":[12]},
{"classID"87,"id of students who missed class":[3,6,8,45,7,9]},{"classID":12,"id of students who missed class":[1,2,74,45,36]},{"classID":20,"id of students who missed class":[2,9,36,5]},
{"classID":41,"id of students who missed class:"[5,6,9,8,7]}]
```

In this case, how should this be my class of binding, an object of type Class and inside it an array of integers, where would the annotations @JsonProperty?

Comment: Would you mind to share a full json?

Comment: @maio290 
json is just like I added in the last part of the post, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use `int[]` to map the ids of the students:

```
public class Attendance {

    @JsonProperty("classID")
    private int classId;

    @JsonProperty("id of students who missed class")
    private int[] missingStudentIds;

}
```

and read your complete JSON as an array:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Attendance[] obj = mapper.readValue(json, Attendance[].class);
```